# What are puppet boxes in Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am learning visualization with Vagrant. I am trying to create a test lab for my DNS server that I have created with FreeBSD using Vagrant. But now I want to install 2 to 3 test boxes to test my DNS server, when I go to vagrant boxes, there is a section called puppet boxes,

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puppetlabs

But I don't exactly know what is the difference between normal boxes and puppet boxes ?

I visited wikipedia to check what puppetlabs is, and it says its a company that provide management of operating systems.

> Puppet IT automation software uses Puppet's declarative language to manage various stages of the IT infrastructure lifecycle, including the provisioning, patching, configuration, and management of operating system and application components across enterprise data centers and cloud infrastructures.

But I don't understand what puppet boxes are, and how they are different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone can host boxes on atlas (i.e. the vagrant-share service provided by hashicorp) so puppetlabs as a company provides you boxes for all major OS specifically designed to work with puppet provisioning.

If you take a box with the same OS that is provided by hashicorp for example, it will contain chef, puppet, ansible -